# Get String of a main function from another class

Tags: java

I have this main function (Class: `DialogBoxForIt.java`):

```
public void main(final SimpleCallback<HashMap<SPARAM, Object>> sr) {
    if(mainwindow == null){
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle(_T.PasswordEncrypt_title.val());
        jf.setResizable(false);
        jf.setIconImages(ResourceCenter.icons);
        jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(jf.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        thiswindow = jf;
    }
    else{
        JDialog jd = new JDialog(mainwindow);
        jd.setModal(true);
        jd.setTitle(_T.PasswordEncrypt_title.val());
        jd.setResizable(false);
        jd.setIconImages(ResourceCenter.icons);
        jd.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(jd.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 
        jd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        thiswindow = jd;
    }

    JPanel line1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    JPanel line2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    JPanel lineok = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel line3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    final JPanel lineopt = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

    final JPasswordField tf = new JPasswordField();
    tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));

    final JPasswordField tf2 = new JPasswordField();
    tf2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));

    final JTextField jtf = new JTextField(""+CryptoCodes.STANDARD_PBKDF2_ITERATIONS); 

    JButton b = new JButton("OK");

    ActionListener act = new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            char[] s1 = tf.getPassword();
            char[] s2 = tf2.getPassword();

            if(s1 == null || s2 == null || s1.length == 0 || s2.length == 0)
                return;

            int minlen = CryptoCodes.STANDARD_PBKDF2_PWLEN;

            tf.setText(DUMMYTEXT);
            tf2.setText(DUMMYTEXT);

            tf.setText("");
            tf2.setText("");

            if(Arrays.equals(s1, s2) && s1.length >= minlen){
                thiswindow.dispose();
                CryptoUtils.kill(s2);

                char[] passw = PasswordGenerator.GenerateRandomString(18,25,3,1,1,1).toCharArray();
                String passwds = String.valueOf(passw);
                try {
                    passwds = new String(passw);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }



                myParams.put(SPARAM.password, passwds.toCharArray());

                System.out.println("let test -- "+String.valueOf((char[])myParams.get(SPARAM.password))) ;


                if(lineopt.isVisible()){
                    String tmp = jtf.getText();
                    if(FilterNumbers.validate(tmp)) myParams.put(SPARAM.itcount, tmp);
                }
                sr.callbackValue(this, myParams);
            }
            else{
                CryptoUtils.kill(s1);
                CryptoUtils.kill(s2);
                tf.requestFocus();

                if(s1.length < minlen)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(thiswindow, _T.PasswordEncrypt_len.msg(minlen));
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(thiswindow, _T.PasswordEncrypt_nomatch);
            }
        }
    };

    b.addActionListener(act);
    tf.addActionListener(act);
    tf2.addActionListener(act);
    jtf.addActionListener(act);

    JLabel jl = new JLabel(_T.PasswordEncrypt_label + ": ");
    line1.add(jl);
    line1.add(tf);
    thiswindow.add(line1);

    jl = new JLabel(_T.PasswordEncrypt_retype + ": ");
    line2.add(jl);
    line2.add(tf2);
    thiswindow.add(line2);

    b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 35));
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = gbc.weighty = 1.0;
    lineok.add(b, gbc);
    thiswindow.add(lineok);

    javax.swing.ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(7000);

    ((PlainDocument) jtf.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new FilterNumbers());
    jtf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));
    jtf.setToolTipText(_T.PasswordEncrypt_itcountdescr.val());
    jl = new JLabel(_T.PasswordEncrypt_itcount + ": ");
    jl.setToolTipText(_T.PasswordEncrypt_itcountdescr.val());
    lineopt.add(jl);
    lineopt.add(jtf);

    final JButton jb = new JButton(new ImageIcon(ResourceCenter.optsup));
    line3.add(jb);
    thiswindow.add(line3);

    thiswindow.add(lineopt);
    lineopt.setVisible(false);

    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(lineopt.isVisible()){
                lineopt.setVisible(false);
                jb.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ResourceCenter.optsup));
            }
            else{
                lineopt.setVisible(true);
                jb.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ResourceCenter.optsdown));
            }

            thiswindow.pack();
        }
    });

    thiswindow.pack();

    thiswindow.setLocationRelativeTo(mainwindow);
    thiswindow.setVisible(true);

    thiswindow.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            try {
                tf.setText(DUMMYTEXT);
                tf2.setText(DUMMYTEXT);

                tf.setText("");
                tf2.setText("");
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
    });

    if(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(thiswindow, _T.Password_caps);
    }
}
```

I call this main function from another class like this (The other class name: `AppTest.java`):

```
new DialogBoxForIt(currentSource).main(this);
```

I want get the passwds String of main function from this class.

How to do that please ?

What changes i must apport in order to get it there ?

You must know that passwds String contain a random generated password, and must be transfered to the other class for another use.

I tried to add public string (`public String passwpub = ""`) and then inside the function (`passwpub = passwds;`), but can't get it from the other class.

If you have any idea will be highly appreciated.

Thank you !

Comment: Don't use the `main`-method. The main-method normally starts a  program. If you want a dialogue in which the user enters the password, look at the corresponding dialogue windows of your GUI-system of choice.

Comment: @Turing85 I have to use the `main` method since it's a separated windows to open a dialogue in order to enter a password. I have to find any trick without make a major changes. Thank you

Comment: Depending on what is regarded as "major change", this may not be possible. The `main` method has a `void` return type, thus you cannot `return` any value. The parameter is also fixed (type `AppTest`). What you could do is add some password-attribute to `AppTes`t and set it within the `main`-method to the value the user entered. In either way, this is a major code smell.

Comment: @Turing85 You mean i will copy all the codes present inside `DialogBoxForIt.java` to the main method of the class `AppTest` ? And call it from there ?

Comment: No. I am unter the impression that `DialogBoxForIt` is the class containing the `main`-method and `AppTest` calls the `main`-method.

Comment: @Turing85 Yes that's right ! the `main` method is inside `DialogBoxForIt.java`

Comment: No. Just add an attribute to `AppTest` for your password (most probably a `String`) and set it within `DialogBoxForIt`'s `main`-method after the user has input it.

Comment: @Turing85 already did that, i added: `public static String passit;` for `AppTest`, and inside main function of DialogBoxForIt: `String passit = passwds;`, This return NULL.

Comment: You seem to have a major misconception on how attributes and classes work. Is this some homework assingment? If so, please speak with your professor/supervisor/teacher.

Comment: @Turing85 I think i did what you suggested to me to do, since i declared an attribute before call the `main` method, and when user enter password i set the attribute with the password and finally trying to show it after the `main` method is called from `AppTest`. Or i misunderstanded your suggestion ? If yes, please clarify more about it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You provide close to 200 lines and when I try to compile it, after surrounding it with a class declaration, I get 90 errors, most of them probably for missing imports. 200 lines of weakly structured code are hard to analyze. You should make it simple for your readers.

Comment: @userunknown I can't provide the full source code, i provide the necessary only ... this is not a question of code, but trying to find a way to resolve a commun problem.

Comment: @BenMarson: Yes, but then you should copy your code to a new class, which you radically reduce to your problem at hand ([mcve]), so we don't have to work ourselves through the mass of unrelated code.

Comment: @userunknown Sorry sir, but my case here is not to share the source code, i given to you the necessary and waiting for suggestions about the way to solve the problem, or the way i must follow to get a correct concept. This is not a question to fix an error in my code, please you have to read again my request and try to understand well my case, thank you anyway for your time.

Comment: No, you posted a bunch of junk and we have to figure out, what is relevant and what not for the problem. Instead of you figuring it out, and only provide that information, to eventually transfer our suggestions for your [mcve] example code to your real problem. The answer to your problem is `String main (...) {... return passwd;}` and `String result = dialogBoxForIt.main (...);`

Comment: What is SimpleCallback, the type of the parameter for main?

Comment: @userunknown can't convert `void main` to `String`, the problem is here ! Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @BenMarson, care to answer my question above?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This is another class that contain: `callbackValue` function. The goal of this one is to do action when password value is received. Sorry i didn't noticied your comment.

Comment: @BenMarson But then you must have an instance of that class when calling main, why not get the password from that instance?

Comment: @BenMarson: So you show us 170 lines of code but miss the most important information, that you can't change the class? And you don't show us the class declaration, whether there is an attribute to inspect?